# Firebase Database with no result

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Functions for my Alexa skill. This is working as expected, but my data in the database is special and sometime the query can't return any value.

My keys are from 0101 to 1231 (MMDD) and if I query after the highest key, I don't get any callback, because firebase hasn't any data.

How can I set the query, that I find in that case the first >= "0101"?

The currently call is

```
admin.database().ref("calendar/birthday")
.orderByKey().startAt(key).limitToFirst(1).once("child_added")
.then(function(snapshot) { ... })
```

My database structure

```
"calendar" : {
  "birthday" : {
      "0111" : {
        ... -> 1st person
      },
      ...
      "0710" : {
        ... -> xth person
      },
      ...
      "1109" : {
        ... -> last person
      }
  }
}
```

My Alexa skill should name the next birthday and it will only work until 09. November and after 01. January, because I don't know how to query the data. Or can I structure my data in a better way to find the next birthday?

Comment: You're likely getting caught by the "array coercion" of the Firebase SDKs. Is there a way that you can change the data and prefix the keys (e.g. "day_0101"). That will prevent the coercion and (if that was the cause of the problem) will fix the problem.

Comment: Sure, I can change the keys, but how will this fix the "no data found" problem? My last key is "1109" and if I call the the above query with "key = '1110'" I won't get any values (right now).

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON that you're querying (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Added the Firebase database structure in a simplified way.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your question better now. Are you asking: how do I know that there are no birthdays matching my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for: how do I know that there are no birthdays matching my query?

In that case you'll need to listen for the `value` event. If you attach that with a `once()`, it fires right away when you attach the query, no matter if there are results or not.

```
admin.database().ref("calendar/birthday")
  .orderByKey().startAt(key).limitToFirst(1).once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log("There are no birthdays on or after "+key);
    }
    else {
      snapshot.forEach(function(daySnapshot) {
        console.log("There is a birthday on "+daySnapshot.key);
      });
    }
  })
```

The `exists()` detects that there were no results matching the query. The `forEach()` loop in the `else` is the result of using `value` with a query. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: I believe OP wanted a way to always get a result by using some wrap-around / round-robin type of query. E.g. when querying for the next birthday after 11th of November (`1111`), it should come back with the birthday on 11th of January (`0111`) instead of "no birthdays". If at least one birthday is in the list, there should never be a "no birthdays" result.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I was looking for. Now I can also search for "next year", if current has no results. I know that I can always count on your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Markus! There is no way to make the search wrap automatically. But indeed, using a `value` event, you can determine that you need to fire a second query.

Comment: But what if I want to get realtime updates and still be able to know if the list of children is empty?